# Automation of Nodeweb-kit using python

Tags: automation

In our product, we have created a standalone application which is a combination of AngularJS and nodeweb-kit. This uses the chrominum browser functionalities which is inbuild with the node-webkit. We need a way to automate this application end to end cases using python. We tired using selenimum for the automation but its not recognizing the application which is running as a browser.

Has anyone tried a automation of this kind of application using python? Please suggest some other tools as well which can used for the automation..